# WPF RichTextBox: Programmatically formatting specific text

Tags: wpf, formatting, richtextbox

Hi: I am trying to implement programmatically selected text formatting in a WPF RichTextBox.

The following code from [How to select text from the RichTextBox and then color it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707120/how-to-select-text-from-the-richtextbox-and-then-color-it) is exactly what i am trying to do. However, as far as i can tell this code is for a WinForms RichTextBox:

```
public void ColourRrbText(RichTextBox rtb)
{
    Regex regExp = new Regex("\b(For|Next|If|Then)\b");

    foreach (Match match in regExp.Matches(rtb.Text))
    {
        rtb.Select(match.Index, match.Length);
        rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
    }
}
```

However, i am stuck on how to fully convert the above code to code that WPF RichTextBox knows how to handle. The following code from [wpf richtextbox selection with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50959130/wpf-richtextbox-selection-with-regex) provides some very helpful guidance. So this is where i am:

```
public static void ColorSpecificText(RichTextBox richTextBox)
{
    var newRun = new Run(); // <-- I THINK I NEED TO RELATE THIS CODE TO MY textRange OR TO MY richTextBox, BUT NOT SURE / DON'T KNOW HOW TO DO IT
    TextRange textRange = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"\b(For|Next|If|Then)\b");

    foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(textRange.Text))
    {
        TextPointer start = newRun.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(match.Index, LogicalDirection.Forward);
        TextPointer end = newRun.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(match.Index + match.Length, LogicalDirection.Backward);
        if (start != null && end != null)
        {
            richTextBox.Selection.Select(start, end);
            richTextBox.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(Run.BackgroundProperty, "Red");
        }
    }
}
```

For example, when applying this code to a WPF RichTextBox with the string "Next Hello World", the above code doesn't generate any errors, but doesn't work either ("Next" doesn't get highlighted). I don't have reason to believe that the regex would be the issue as i tested it at regex101.com. My guess is i am missing something in declaring newRun and how to relate it either to textRange or richTextBox. Thanks for any guidance on how to resolve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selected Text Formatting in WPF RichTexBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61251128/selected-text-formatting-in-wpf-richtexbox)

Comment: @Ash: Partially yes. I was instructed to resubmit my question asked in that earlier post. But there is a comment that the approach described there is not enough to create a proper TextPointer. The proposed solution is definitely super helpful, but my question now is what is the proper syntax to create a proper TextPointer (which is what i tried to do unsuccessfully in the above code)?